# Isotope@3.0.6 has undefined in window.Isotope.Item

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have got

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined
    at isotope.js:54
    at isotope.js:59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you including Isotope in your project?

I got that same error after using Node Package Manager (`npm install isotope-layout --save` from the terminal) and referencing isotope.js directly from the node_modules folder in my project:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/isotope-layout/js/isotope.js"></script>`

When I instead used the version of isotope available on the CDN:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>`

isotope initialized successfully.